# rhc can only be used from the command line

Tags: git, cmd, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I installed the rhc toolkit from openshift on a windows 7 machine. I am also running git on this machine. However, after installation the rhc toolkit is only found in the cmd of windows and not in the git console:

```
$ rhc
sh.exe": /c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/bin/rhc: "C:/Program: bad interpreter
: No such file or directory
```

Any recommendations how to fix that?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go through the installation of both ruby and git you need to select a few options that will make it usable on the command line. I put together a screencast that will walk you through step by step here https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-install-the-openshift-rhc-client-tools-on-windows

Comment: you shouldn't need to remove them, just run through the video and you should be all set.

Comment: Would it be possible to update your answer with at least a summary of the steps?

Comment: Absolutely! I'll get started on that later today.

Comment: Actually on second thought... Everything is layed out nicely with screenshots and everything on the link I posted. Re-writing all that here would be a bit redundant don't you think? I'm more than happy to write more instructions on any topic, but I'm just not seeing the value in doing it twice :).